# What do i use to run Minecraft Forge Files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

Ok, so I want to run a forge file for Minecraft. I double clicked it thinking it would open and all I would have to do is install the client. But it said What do you want to use to open this file. So i clicked Java(TM) Platform SE Binary. But every time i select it then double click the file, it comes up with a Java Control Panel. I jhave no idea what this is or how to use it, and the apply button is greyed out. Can somebody help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know where i can ask these questions? Im sorry, my bad.

Comment: Only modded minecraft crash support is off topic, not everything to do with modded minecraft.